# How to handle spoon err: Permission Denied in Redis

Tags: windows, redis, permissions, redis-cli, redis-server

I'm new to Redis (but already an enthusiastic user) and I'm facing this error on Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) when trying to do the background save of Redis:

```
[14932] 18 Jan 10:57:24 # Failed saving the DB: Permission denied
[14932] 18 Jan 10:57:24 # Can't save in background: spoon err: Permission denied
[14932] 18 Jan 10:57:24 # Background saving terminated by signal 255
```

(This is the detailed message given by redis-server, the console would just print ERR after BGSAVE command).

I've tried to restart and to change User permissions to the redis.conf file but I'm not sure how to edit it manually. My Redis version is earlier than 2.8.0.

Can anybody please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a lack of permission in the dir directory or dbfilename. You can find the dir definition in the redis.conf file. For example:

dir "C:/Program Files/Redis/data"

dbfilename dump.rdb

In my case, after adjusting the permissions in the data directory, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I run with `run as administrator` and the problem has been solved

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).